# How to call my function inside another function

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently trying to implement functionality that deletes all translations within a project when a user deletes a project. However, when I try to call my `deleteTranslations` function within my `deleteProject` function, it says `deleteTranslations` is not defined.

```js
deleteTranslations: async({
    user,
    projectId,
    trkeys
  }) => {
    const deletePromises = trkeys.map(async(trkey) => {
      const params = {
        ...getBaseParams(),
        Key: {
          PK: getPK('trans', user, projectId),
          SK: getSK('trans', user, projectId, trkey),
        },
      };
      return doDelete(params);
    });
    return Promise.all(deletePromises);
  },

  deleteProject: async({
    user,
    project
  }) => {
    const translationsParams = {
      user,
      projectId: project,
      trkeys: [],
    };
    await deleteTranslations(translationsParams); // the problem is here

    const params = {
      TableName: table,
      Key: {
        PK: getPK('project', user),
        SK: getSK('project', user, project),
      },
    };
    return doDelete(params);
  },
}
```

I've tried to implement this in a few ways but I cant wrap my head around this.

Comment: Why do you have a function inside another in the first place?

Comment: my plan is that when you delete a project, it will go ahead and delete all the projects translations first before the project is deleted

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the error with minimal code - the following snippet will fail with a reference error.

```js
const obj = {
    deleteTranslations: (steps) => {
        console.log(steps);
        if (steps-1 >= 0) {
            deleteTranslations(steps-1);
        }
    }
};

obj.deleteTranslations(5)
```

While it may not be the exact setup you're using, it certainly portrays the error(s) you're running into.

The first error would be trying to access a key within an object without referencing `this`. Whenever you want to access something from the current context, `this` has to be prepended, like such:

```js
const obj = {
  someOtherProperty: 5,
  someFnProperty: function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.someOtherProperty);
  },
};

obj.someFnProperty()
```

The above snippet will log the context the function is called within - which is `obj` - and list all of its properties. By accessing the context through `this` we can also access other properties within the context.

You may have noticed me using the `function` keyword, rather than using an arrow function. This is also due to context-reasons and the "second" error you're running into. [Here's a great article](https://www.codementor.io/@dariogarciamoya/understanding-this-in-javascript-with-arrow-functions-gcpjwfyuc) on how `this` works when looking at "regular" functions vs. arrow functions.

I'd consider refactoring your code to use stand-alone functions as this *can* be fixed but doesn't look all too clean. Here's a working version:

```js
const obj = {
    deleteTranslations: function(steps) {
        console.log(steps);
        if (steps-1 >= 0) {
            this.deleteTranslations(steps-1);
        }
    }
};

obj.deleteTranslations(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use DynamoDB Transactions for this, so long as there is not more than 100 translations. This allows you to delete all translations and project in a single ATOMIC operation. Psuedo would look like this:

1. Get Project and all project translations
2. Create a params for DynamoDB Transaction

- Add project key
- Add list of translations

3. Execute transaction (which deletes all of the items, if one fail, they all fail)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/classes/transactwriteitemscommand.html

Answer (score -2):

you are trying to use the function inside it self and that's not correct

Comment: A function can totally call itself. Ever heard of [recursion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion)?